Binance Futures Websocket doesn't push informations
So my code is split among different scripts. The title of the scripts should be self explanatory.
import threading
import socket
from strategies import detect_significant_changes
from websocket_manager import WebSocketManager

# Binance API credentials (replace with your own)
api_key = 'your_api_key'
api_secret = 'your_api_secret'

# Global Variables
watchlist = ["BTCUSDT", "ETHUSDT", "BNBUSDT", "ADAUSDT", "XRPUSDT"]  # Replace with your desired watchlist

# Initialize WebSocket Manager
ws_manager = WebSocketManager(api_key, api_secret)

# Command Control Flags
start_bot = threading.Event()
stop_bot = threading.Event()

# Socket server settings
SERVER_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
SERVER_PORT = 65432

def handle_websocket_data(msg):
    """
    Process the incoming WebSocket data and apply the strategy.
    :param msg: WebSocket message data
    """
    if not msg:
        print("[ERROR] Received empty WebSocket message.")
        return

    print(f"[DEBUG] Raw WebSocket message: {msg}")  # Print the entire message structure

    # Ensure the message has the required fields
    if isinstance(msg, dict) and 's' in msg and 'k' in msg:  # Check if expected fields are present
        symbol = msg['s']  # Get the symbol
        if 'c' in msg['k']:
            close_price = float(msg['k']['c'])  # Extract closing price from kline data
            print(f"[DEBUG] Symbol: {symbol}, Close Price: {close_price}")  # Print to confirm values
            detect_significant_changes(symbol, close_price)  # Execute strategy
        else:
            print(f"[ERROR] 'c' (closing price) not found in the kline data for symbol {symbol}. Full message: {msg}")
    else:
        print(f"[ERROR] Unexpected message format received: {msg}")

def handle_client_connection(client_socket):
    """
    Handle incoming commands from the control script.
    :param client_socket: Socket connection from control script
    """
    command = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
    print(f"Received command: {command}")

    if command == "start":
        if start_bot.is_set():
            # If the bot is already running, treat it as a restart
            print("Bot is already running. Restarting...")
            ws_manager.disconnect_all_streams()
        print("Start command received. Starting the bot...")
        start_bot.set()
        stop_bot.clear()
        print(f"[DEBUG] Setting up callback for WebSocketManager.")
        ws_manager.set_callback(handle_websocket_data)  # Set callback for WebSocketManager
        print(f"[DEBUG] Callback set successfully.")
        ws_manager.reconnect_streams(watchlist)
    elif command == "pause":
        print("Pause command received. Pausing the bot...")
        ws_manager.disconnect_all_streams()
        stop_bot.set()
        start_bot.clear()
    elif command == "break":
        print("Break command received. Stopping the bot...")
        ws_manager.disconnect_all_streams()
        start_bot.clear()
        print("Exiting...")
        client_socket.close()
        exit(0)
    else:
        print("Unknown command. Please enter 'start', 'pause', or 'break'.")

    client_socket.close()

def start_server():
    """
    Start the socket server to listen for commands.
    """
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
    server_socket.listen(5)
    print(f"Server started, waiting for commands at {SERVER_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT}...")

    while True:
        client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
        print(f"Connection established with {addr}")
        handle_client_connection(client_socket)

def main():
    print("Initializing bot...")
    print("Bot initialized and waiting for commands (start, pause, break).")
    
    # Start the server in a separate thread
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_server, daemon=True)
    server_thread.start()

    # Automatically start the bot on the first run
    print(f"[DEBUG] Setting up callback for WebSocketManager.")
    ws_manager.set_callback(handle_websocket_data)
    print(f"[DEBUG] Callback function set: {ws_manager.callback}")

    first_run = True
    if first_run:
        print("[AUTO-START] First run detected. Automatically starting the bot...")
        start_bot.set()
        stop_bot.clear()
        ws_manager.reconnect_streams(watchlist)  # Automatically connect to the streams
        first_run = False

    # Keep the bot running to handle commands in the background
    server_thread.join()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


websocketmanager.py:
from binance.websocket.um_futures.websocket_client import UMFuturesWebsocketClient
import threading

class WebSocketManager:
    def __init__(self, api_key, api_secret):
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.api_secret = api_secret
        self.ws_client = None  # Initialize as None to avoid attribute errors
        self.active_streams = {}  # Dictionary to store active streams
        self.callback = None  # Strategy callback function to handle data
        self.stream_lock = threading.Lock()

    def initialize_client(self):
        """
        Ensure that the WebSocket client is initialized.
        """
        if not self.ws_client:
            self.ws_client = UMFuturesWebsocketClient()
            print("[DEBUG] UMFuturesWebsocketClient initialized.")

    def set_callback(self, callback_function):
        """
        Set the callback function to be used for handling WebSocket data.
        :param callback_function: Function to process the incoming data
        """
        self.callback = callback_function
        print(f"[DEBUG] Callback function set: {self.callback}")

    def connect_stream(self, symbol):
        """
        Connect a WebSocket stream for a given symbol.
        :param symbol: Symbol to connect (e.g., "BTCUSDT")
        """
        self.initialize_client()
        if self.callback is None:
            raise ValueError("Callback function is not set. Use `set_callback()` before connecting streams.")
        
        # Define the internal callback for handling data
        def internal_callback(msg):
            print(f"[DEBUG] Raw message received for {symbol}: {msg}")  # Log every raw message received
            if not msg:
                print(f"[ERROR] No data received from WebSocket stream for {symbol}")
                return
            else:
                print(f"[DEBUG] Valid message received for {symbol}")

            if self.callback:
                print(f"[DEBUG] Passing message for {symbol} to the main handler.")
                self.callback(msg)  # Pass the message to the strategy handler
            else:
                print(f"[ERROR] No callback defined to handle data for {symbol}.")

        # Add stream for the given symbol
        with self.stream_lock:
            print(f"[DEBUG] Attempting to connect to WebSocket for {symbol}...")
            try:
                self.ws_client.kline(
                    symbol=symbol.lower(),
                    interval='1m',
                    callback=internal_callback
                )
                print(f"[DEBUG] WebSocket connection established for {symbol}.")
                self.active_streams[symbol] = True
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"[ERROR] Failed to connect WebSocket for {symbol}: {e}")

    def disconnect_stream(self, symbol):
        """
        Disconnect a WebSocket stream for a given symbol.
        :param symbol: Symbol to disconnect (e.g., "BTCUSDT")
        """
        with self.stream_lock:
            if symbol in self.active_streams:
                print(f"[DEBUG] Disconnecting WebSocket for {symbol}...")
                del self.active_streams[symbol]
                self.ws_client.stop()
                print(f"[DEBUG] WebSocket for {symbol} disconnected.")

    def disconnect_all_streams(self):
        """
        Disconnect all active WebSocket streams.
        """
        with self.stream_lock:
            if self.ws_client:
                self.ws_client.stop()  # Check if the client is initialized before stopping
                print("[DEBUG] All WebSocket connections stopped.")
            else:
                print("[DEBUG] No active WebSocket client to disconnect.")
            self.active_streams = {}

    def reconnect_streams(self, symbols):
        """
        Reconnect all WebSocket streams for a given list of symbols.
        :param symbols: List of symbols to reconnect (e.g., ["BTCUSDT", "ETHUSDT"])
        """
        print("[DEBUG] Reconnecting WebSocket streams for all symbols...")
        self.disconnect_all_streams()
        self.initialize_client()  # Ensure the client is re-initialized if needed
        for symbol in symbols:
            self.connect_stream(symbol)

    def close(self):
        """
        Safely close the WebSocket client and disconnect all streams.
        """
        print("[DEBUG] Closing WebSocketManager...")
        self.disconnect_all_streams()
        if self.ws_client:
            self.ws_client.stop()
            print("[DEBUG] All WebSocket connections closed.")


strategies.py:
# strategies.py
# Strategy functions to handle trading logic

# Parameters for strategies (easy to configure)
lookback_period = 60  # Lookback period in seconds
increase_threshold = 0.01  # % increase to trigger a notification
decrease_threshold = -0.01  # % decrease to trigger a notification
tracked_prices = {}  # Dictionary to store the price history for each coin

def detect_significant_changes(symbol, price):
    print(f"[DEBUG] detect_significant_changes called for {symbol} at price {price}")
    if symbol not in tracked_prices:
        tracked_prices[symbol] = [price]
    else:
        tracked_prices[symbol].append(price)
        
        if len(tracked_prices[symbol]) > lookback_period:
            tracked_prices[symbol].pop(0)

    initial_price = tracked_prices[symbol][0]
    percent_change = ((price - initial_price) / initial_price) * 100

    print(f"[DEBUG] {symbol}: Initial Price = {initial_price}, Current Price = {price}, Change = {percent_change:.2f}%")

    if percent_change >= increase_threshold:
        print(f"[INFO] {symbol} has increased by {percent_change:.2f}% over the lookback period.")
    elif percent_change <= decrease_threshold:
        print(f"[INFO] {symbol} has decreased by {percent_change:.2f}% over the lookback period.")


control.py:
import socket

# Define server address and port
SERVER_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
SERVER_PORT = 65432

def send_command(command):
    """Send a command to the bot."""
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client_socket.connect((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
    client_socket.send(command.encode())
    client_socket.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Control client for the bot.")
    print("Available commands: 'start', 'pause', 'break'")

    while True:
        command = input("Enter command: ").strip().lower()
        if command in ['start', 'pause', 'break']:
            send_command(command)
            if command == 'break':
                print("Exiting control script.")
                break
        else:
            print("Invalid command. Try again.")


And this is the console output:
Initializing bot...
Bot initialized and waiting for commands (start, pause, break).
[DEBUG] Setting up callback for WebSocketManager.
[DEBUG] Callback function set: <function handle_websocket_data at 0x0000020EB8D8D3A0>
[DEBUG] Callback function set: <function handle_websocket_data at 0x0000020EB8D8D3A0>
[AUTO-START] First run detected. Automatically starting the bot...
[DEBUG] Reconnecting WebSocket streams for all symbols...
[DEBUG] No active WebSocket client to disconnect.
Server started, waiting for commands at 127.0.0.1:65432...
[DEBUG] UMFuturesWebsocketClient initialized.
[DEBUG] Attempting to connect to WebSocket for BTCUSDT...
[DEBUG] WebSocket connection established for BTCUSDT.
[DEBUG] Attempting to connect to WebSocket for ETHUSDT...
[DEBUG] WebSocket connection established for ETHUSDT.
[DEBUG] Attempting to connect to WebSocket for BNBUSDT...
[DEBUG] WebSocket connection established for BNBUSDT.
[DEBUG] Attempting to connect to WebSocket for ADAUSDT...
[DEBUG] WebSocket connection established for ADAUSDT.
[DEBUG] Attempting to connect to WebSocket for XRPUSDT...
[DEBUG] WebSocket connection established for XRPUSDT.

Please help me since even with my debugging logic I don't get any error or debug message.
I tried to implement debug logic but it doesn't show me anything.
